# pulseaudio not working

Tags: sound

pulaseaudio seems to be working, but no sound. after totally deleting audio and spending a week trying to fix it, i have concluded that i am lost. 
ubuntu version 12.04

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

the last part of (pkill pulseaudio; sleep 2; pulseaudio -vv) seems to have the word suspended in it a lot?
I: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Device suspended...
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: All sinks and sources are suspended, vacuuming memory
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC0 is accessible: yes

removed all audio, oops bad idea, been a week now and need help, thanks

Comment: i need help please

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Been using linux from the late 90's. ALSA all the way, pulseaudio comes along. I can't get any sound out of any debian or ubuntu systems. Can on other distros like gentoo which don't have pulse audio, but debian based distros are ruined by this.

Answer (score 5):

There is a chance you have not initialized alsa, try

```
alsactl init
```

If this gets your speaker working again make sure alsa starts every time you boot by following this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15765/why-do-i-have-to-run-alsactl-init-each-time-i-boot-my-system)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing and re-installing alsa and pulseaudio:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload`

See this [unixmen tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/) if it doesn't work.

Comment: DONT DO THIS! For some reason in Linux Mint 19.3 it removed cinnamon too and then my system got broken!

Comment: You might want to consider the time in which this was posted before blindly doing something

Comment: I did `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`  after the command from @Jonathan.
The audio is working again just after that..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that pulseaudio is in the `audio` group:

```
sudo addgroup pulse audio
sudo service pulseaudio restart
```

Comment: You can check the current groups with `groups pulse`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Jonathans answer worked for me after somehow messing up my sound configuration, running ubuntu 18.04 on my old Dell XPS L702X.

Works as it was originally.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searching i got this and it worked for me !

```
sudo apt remove pulseaudio*
sudo apt remove pavucontrol*
sudo apt install pavucontrol
sudo reboot
```